# How to type a custom createAsyncThunk wrapper

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I have this thunk wrapper which I initally used in a js app.

Therefore, I'm struggling to figure out how to type it, mostly because of the `thunk` and the `thunkApi` types:

```
export const asyncThunkHandleError = (
  typePrefix: string,
  thunk: any, // how to type this one and thunkAPI?
  errorMessage?: string
) =>
  createAsyncThunk(typePrefix, async (arg: any, thunkAPI: any) => {
    try {
      // actually call the thunk
      return await thunk(arg, thunkAPI);
    } catch (error: any) {
      // here we will dispatch the modal with the error message
      thunkAPI.dispatch(
        openModal({
          title: `Error in ${typePrefix}`,
          children: `${error instanceof Error ? error.message : 'Unknown error'}`,
        })
      );
      throw thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.response?.data || errorMessage);
    }
  });
```

It's dispatched like this:

```
// SomeComponent.tsx
dispatch(getPokemons());
```

The thunk is wrapped like so:

```
// actions/pokemons.ts
const getPokemons = asyncThunkHandleError(
  'pokemons/getPokemons',
  async (arg: any, thunkAPI: any) => {
    const someNetworkCall = await fetch('https://example.com');

    return someNetworkCall.json();
  },
  'An error occurred'
);
```

I've been checking in the dependency files and kind of found something types like `BaseThunkAPI`, `GetThunkAPI`, `AsyncThunkPayloadCreator` etc in the path `.../@reduxjs/toolkit/src/createAsyncThunk.ts` but I'm not sure how to implement it or if it's even correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a solution for a similar case [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/486), it even has a [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwMZQKYEMaoIIGcCeAdkgCoAWAroQNYA0eRplNACuvgDYToAmAwmkzR6BYuSrUAvnABmUCCDgByAAJoeFAB4ArXAHoYECB2rAYSgFAXghLFBnokqOOJrYWAST4RCM4AHNESStUTUhYOCQfXHgUDCwAWXwAeQB3QgYxZmo4AF44AB4AJVQYCihCVB5aF2zsKED89EJ8AD4ACgs4OBh8MFQALjgYqBt-Wi6e7KHMpgk2Tm5%20QUMoYtLyyuraiXr-VpruuD09QoBaM7gAN1QofDgqXHLnCBkp4Fw4S7J0G57RqpwEDNe4wMhjT5kW6oCwAShmojmNHWZQqVRqrmoewxdU83l8AVaeSJCEmaFRhEiKxwiMxKM26J2bgaON2eJ8fn2nSOPT6qAmPPQiLg7XQLKmbI8sOJiEmPJgd1lPJ5JzgPAgwwUzhiFBkbyhaCmmDgPzA-UInx8cFQN0VjhgwB8cuV5M2cHQqXQZglNFF4rBkthzu60iQmCQZBFtyg0tJyqOqvVmpA2rKepN0KN8FN5stlJtt3u0egwaOroqPqxngAdGhtKgkDAAOpmMgANXQHAoqHahAoHA4QfjwR5kgFcCDwQsUQt8BA%20ExeSp8VQSTSGVp2XaACIZEZtzV2tLckTd-ugxZVWCPnAb4Y4AAjZyhfqNxn4CAUNXAHhwQgQeBen6d0Gh6DUAAMrggH9wIsedMSPKwZxiIEF2yAAmJc4kwVcUnSWY6RGMZaCgn8OjPCADxFY9Tz3SiL3gjCjyAA):

```
import {createAsyncThunk,AsyncThunkPayloadCreator,AsyncThunk} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

interface ThunkAPIConfig {}

export const createMyOwnAsyncThunk = <Returned, ThunkArg = any>(
  type: string,
  thunk: AsyncThunkPayloadCreator<Returned, ThunkArg>,    // <-- very unsure of this - have tried many things here
): AsyncThunk<Returned, ThunkArg, ThunkAPIConfig> => {
  return createAsyncThunk<Returned, ThunkArg, ThunkAPIConfig>(
    type,
    async (arg, thunkAPI) => {
      try {
        // do some stuff here that happens on every action
        return await thunk(arg, thunkAPI)
      } catch (err) {
        // do some stuff here that happens on every error
        return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(null)
      }
    },
  )
}
```